# How can I respond to a browser POST request in a way that does not cause navigation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post

**tl;dr** -- Is there a kind of response I can send to a browser's [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request (from my web server running [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)/[Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js)) that will prevent the browser from navigating to a new page and breaking any open [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) connections?

I am implementing the new [Sign In With Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference) [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) flow from a pure client-sided React app that uses WebSocket for bi-directional communication.

The new *Sign in With Google* flow uses either a pre-loaded HTML or JavaScript component to render a button for logging in. Clicking the button opens a new window where the user can consent to sharing data and either log in with a Google account or select an existing logged-in account.

Once complete, the *Sign-In With Google* flow will provide an identity token either via a callback function or a POST request to specified URL. I want to use the second approach to POST the token to a `https://my-server/googleLoginComplete` endpoint. The endpoint will perform some internal login and session operations, and then communicate to the browser/client via an open WebSocket connection that the login operation is complete.

I have everything working, except for one issue. Google's API is performing a [form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_form) POST to send the identity token to the developer supplied endpoint, and any response that I return from that endpoint will cause a navigation change in the browser which breaks the web socket connection.

If I had control over the *Sign In With Google* API, I could do the equivalent of a `form.submit.preventDefault()` and instead just use a `fecth` or `xmlHttpRequest` to perform the POST without navigating to a new page. Unfortunately, Google does not provide this or a similar option, nor do they even have the source code for their new client publicly available.

I've tried sending a 204 and 304 response, an empty object, a generic 200, sending a redirect back to the same URL the browser is already on, not sending anything back at all, destroying the resp completely, and some other variations. But I can't find anything that will simply result in the browser doing nothing. And the web socket connection remains open.

Here is some skeleton code:

```js
// React: '/login.js'

export default function Login() {
  // ...

  return (
    <Row>
      <div id="g_id_onload"
           data-client_id="my-client-id"
           data-login_uri="http://localhost:5000/googleLoginComplete"
           data-auto_prompt="false">
      </div>
      <div className="g_id_signin"
           data-type="standard"
           data-size="large"
           data-theme="outline"
           data-text="sign_in_with"
           data-shape="rectangular"
           data-logo_alignment="left">
      </div>
    </Row>
  )
}
```

```js
// Node.js/Express.js: 'app.js'

//...
app.post('/googleLoginComplete', (req, res) => {
  const googleIdentToken = req.body.credential;

  const sessionId = doSomeInternalSessionStuff(googleIdentToken);
  socket.emit('login.success', {sessionId});

  // Something here to just cause the browser to do nothing
  res.send('ignore this and dont do any navigation');
});
```

(I know that I can change the Sign In With Goole method to use a callback instead, but to keep this consistent with other federated auth providers, I want to use the URL redirect option).

Comment: Further investigation shows that both Firefox and Chrome are unloading the page (which I can see by adding a `window.onbeforeunload` handler) in response to the POST request, even when then response is a 204 (which according to multiple sources should not cause a page navigation).